# Read and modify txt file (line by line)

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, structure

So there was this light project in one of my past classes where the user would read a text file (lets call it "studentstuff.txt", see below)

```
*studentstuff.txt*

1
Bob Smith
24
3.5
2
Jill Williams
23
3.6
3
Tom Jones
32
2.4
4
Julie Jackson
21
3.1
5
Al Brown
23
3.35
6
Juan Garcia
22
3.4
-7
Melissa Davis
20
3.2
8
Jack Black
44
1.1
```

and the output would print out: 1) # of students 2) Average age 3) Average gpa. In this assignment we had a struct:

```
typedef struct{
    int id;
    char name[255];
    int age;
    float gpa;
}student;
```

According to the program, the "studentstuff.txt" will be read and sorted according to the struct and then after some little math and functions spits out the:

- '#' of students:
- Average age:
- Average gpa:

The problem is I have the idea in my head, but I cant seem to put it into code. Could anyone help me out on this?

Comment: Provide at least the [mcve] around the code you cannot put into C. I.e. main(), scan & Co, printf. And take the [tour], looking especially for [ask].

Comment: I do not see the need for sorting. But if sorting is used just for fun, should the result overwrite the input file? The title seems says "line by line" which does not match a whole-file-operation like sorting. And, as long as you do not overwrite the whole file afterwards, there is no "modifying" happending either.

Answer (score 0):

as with any programming problem the first action (after deciding the inputs and outputs) is the breaking down of the problem into simple discrete steps.

Such a set of steps for the OPs problem would look similar to:

```
open the input file
if any errors:
    output user message to stderr
    exit program, indicating error occurred 
else
    begin: loop:
        input the info for one student
        if any errors, except EOF:
            output user message to stderr
            cleanup by closing the input file
            exit program, indicating an error occurred
        else
            update number of students
            update total age
            update total gpa
        endif
        goto top of loop
    end loop:
endif

calculate the average age
calculate the average gpa

display number of students
display average student age
display average student gpa

cleanup by closing the input file
return to caller, indicating success
```

Because the calculations will produce fractions, to avoid problems, suggest the struct be defined as:

```
struct studentStruct
{
    float id;
    char  name[255];
    float age;
    float gpa;
};

typedef struct studentStruct student;
```

Notice the separation of the struct definition from the typedef statement.  It does not make any difference here, but will when working with a debugger (which needs the struct tag name to properly display all fields in the struct) and when working with large projects to help avoid confusion.